# Edit object list

Tags: c#

i have an List of objects. my object is NetworkAdapter that represent the Network Card on my machine. this Network Card has the property ID for example: {1106B232-363f-417F-9DC9-643BB02BEDE2} and of course Ip Address, name etc.

constructor:

```
   public NetworkAdapter(LivePacketDevice packetDevice)
        {
            livePacketDevice = packetDevice;
        }
```

class members:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string ID { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string IPAddress { get; set; }
private string gatewayIpAddress;
public string Speed { get; set; }
public string NetworkInterfaceType { get; set; }
public string MacAddress { get; set; }
private LivePacketDevice livePacketDevice;
public PacketDevice PacketDevice { get { return livePacketDevice; } }
```

my method who get all machine adapters:

```
public static NetworkAdapter[] getAll()
{
    List<NetworkAdapter> list = new List<NetworkAdapter>();
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uniCast in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (!System.Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                StringBuilder gatewayIPAddresses = new StringBuilder();
                string gatewayIPAddressesDisplay = string.Empty;
                foreach (var address in adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
                {
                    gatewayIPAddresses.Append(address.Address);
                    gatewayIPAddresses.Append(" ");
                }

                if (gatewayIPAddresses.Length > 0)
                {
                    gatewayIPAddressesDisplay = gatewayIPAddresses.ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
                }

                list.Add(new NetworkAdapter(getDevice(adapter.Id))
                {
                    Name = adapter.Name,
                    ID = adapter.Id,
                    Description = adapter.Description,
                    IPAddress = uniCast.Address.ToString(),
                    NetworkInterfaceType = adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString(),
                    Speed = adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0"),
                    MacAddress = getMacAddress(adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()),
                    gatewayIpAddress = gatewayIPAddressesDisplay
                });
            }
        }

    return list.GroupBy(n => n.ID).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
}
```

at the end of this method i return the list after combine all the same Network Card:

```
return list.GroupBy(n => n.ID).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
```

so now it solved my problem and i can see only once each adapter and all my adapter's properties are displayed on my form via labels.
what i want to do i don't know how is take all the Ip Addresses from the same adapter (with the same id) and show them together for example:

i configured 3 Ip Addresses on the same adapter: `192.168.0.100,  192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.102`

so i want to edit my object in in the Ip Address property i want to add to the IP the rest of the Ips and instead of **192.168.0.100** it become **192.168.0.100, 101, 102** (this property is string)

Comment: A suggestion would be to make IPAddress to List<string>.  In this way you can have many IP addresses associated with single adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
return list.GroupBy(n => n.ID).Select(g => new NetworkAdapter()
        {
            Description = g.First().Description,
            ID = g.Key,
            IPAddress = string.Join(",", g.Select(v => v.IPAddress)),
            MacAddress = g.First().MacAddress,
            Name = g.First().Name,
            NetworkInterfaceType = g.First().NetworkInterfaceType,
            Speed = g.First().Speed
        }).ToList();
```

you have `192.168.0.100, 192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.102` need to process this to `92.168.0.100, 101, 102`